# Error 2079 when animating using swc file in Starling

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

`TypeError: Error #2079: Classes derived from Bitmap can only be associated with defineBits characters (bitmaps).
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at MainMovie2()
    at MyCustomAnim()`

The line where this error occurs is 
`var anim:MovieClip = new MyCustomAnim();`

I'm adding this animation as

`Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(anim);`

**Edit:**
I found the solution for anybody who is interested. The issue is with Mac somehow. If I compile my project from Windows and use that build this doesn't happens.

Comment: `MyCustomAnim` is extending `bitmap` ?

Comment: No its name of .swc file

Comment: I see you using native flash display classes instead of Starling classes , what exactly you doing ?

Comment: trying to use Flash animation over Starling display

Comment: and did you try to embed the animation in other ways , not in `swc` ?

Comment: Yes I created some animations with code and some with sprite sheets as well. All others are working fine. This also works but just raises an exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31230/discussion-between-husyn-and-cherniv)